# What do grey bullet points mean in chrome lighthouse score?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, lighthouse

I'm trying to assess the performance of my site and finding that some audits are grey.

I assumed that great was "not applicable", but since there are plenty of images on the page the width/height audit should surely be green or red?

Also, there are some grey audits that are passing, and some that aren't, which seems odd.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Grey means they are purely informative.** (there are no metrics for this item, it is there for information and to direct you to new techniques, items that need considering etc. etc.)

If an item is not applicable it will show under "passed audits", if an item is applicable it will show under "diagnostics".

For example, "long-tasks'" will only show if there is a long task. It is possible to still get a high score for "Total Blocking Time" even if you have one or two long tasks (more than 50ms) but it is useful information to know if you have any long tasks.

For further clarity: if you had 1 long task it would show under "diagnostics", if you had no long tasks it would show under "passed audits". Either way it is only informational and would always be grey.